# Does Angularjs has ng-bind-html-template directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, data-binding, directive

I have a directive that can have dynamic templates with expressions inside them.

If I use `ng-bind-html`, the expression won't evaluate and if I use `ng-bin-template`, the HTML part will come back as text (encoded HTML) and not HTML.

So is there a something like `ng-bind-html-template`? Or do I have to make it myself?

Right now, I'm using a function to allow the developer to return the rendered HTML itself but would prefer to use a template.

UPDATE:  @charlietfl
"dynamic templates" means something that is dynamic and is defined by the end user and i don't know what's inside it.

Here's my code:

```js
// Columns definition in directive's config provided by the user
columns: [
    {
        title: 'نام سنجه',
        name: 'measurename',
        key: 'measurecode',
        headerTemplate: function (content, col) {
            return col.title + " <small><span class='label label-info'>واحد</span></small>";
        },
        template: function (item, content, col) {
            return item.measurename + " <small><span class=\'label label-info\'>" + item.unitname + "</span></small>";
        }
    }
],
```

How it gets rendered:

```js
$scope.renderHeaderCell = function (col) {
    var content = col.title;

    if (isFunction(col.headerTemplate)) {
        var _content = col.headerTemplate(content, col);
        if (angular.isDefined(_content) && _content !== false) {
             content = _content;
        } else if (angular.isDefined(col.headerTemplate)) {
            content = col.headerTemplate;
            // If this is not used, the HTML content will be encoded to be safe
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(content);
        };
    }
}
```

How it gets used in the template:

```html
<td ng-repeat="col in config.columns" width="200" ng-bind-html="renderHeaderCell(col)"></td>
```

However, I want to pass the template to the config like this:

```js
headerTemplate: "{{col.title}} <small><span class='label label-info'>واحد</span></small>",
```

and use it in the template like this:

```html
<td ng-repeat="col in config.columns" width="200" ng-bind-html-template="col.headerTemplate"></td>
```

Comment: Would help to understand what you mean by dynamic templates and how you reference them in directive. There are numerous ways of managing templates in directives

Comment: Have you checked `ng-include`

Comment: @Chandermani yes i have tried it, but i couldn't get it to work. each column item need to create a ng-template script with unique id and content. even if it worked it would be a dirty code. can u give a sample on how to do this with `ng-include` ?

Comment: still a bit confusing how user templates would get mapped to there insertion point. Just based on the `<td>` shown you should be able to use directive template itself to replace the `<td>` or use a child directive. Directive templates basically do what you are calling `bind-html-template`

Comment: Your code looks a bit broken. There's some missing brackets in your code. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$sce.trustAsHtml` and `ng-bind-html`.
In your controller set your source as trusted:

```
vm.Overview = $sce.trustAsHtml(Overview)
```

HTML:

```
<p ng-bind-html="vm.Overview"></p>
```